# How do I control blight in lantanas?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, blight

All my [Lantanas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lantana) have this blight on their leaves. What is causing it and how can I cure it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your location isn't in your profile - adding it will help folks help you.

My best guess is entomosporium, especially if you get the leaves wet when watering, or live where it rains a lot.  I can't find a good reference, but see [this GardenWeb post](http://forums.gardenweb.com/forums/load/pests/msg0422050328164.html), especially [the photo](http://forums.gardenweb.com/forums/pests/msg0422050328164.jpg).  Of course, bear in mind that this is just another forum.

Comment: This gets me started.  Thanks for your help, Ed.

Comment: @Bob: Welcome to Gardening.SE. The best way to say thanks is to upvote or by clicking the green checkmark over there on the left to accept this answer. Also, as Ed mentions, if you mention your location -- even in vague terms like "Pacific Northwest" -- it's easier for us to give you a better answer.